# MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException: An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, nginx, ssl, mailkit

I am using MailKit to send emails. While testing the .Net code on my localhost machine it sends successfully, however when I run the code on my Ubuntu machine running on Nginx it shows an SSLHandshakeException. Also on the nginx error.log file it shows the errors:

> SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14209102:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol)
> SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1420918C:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:version too low)

The supported protocols on the server are TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2

Comment: What does your code look like? What .NET framework/version are you using? Which runtime? (Mono vs dotnet)?

Comment: Also, what is MailKit connecting to and the port/protocol scheme?

Comment: I am using .Net framework version 5 and runtime dotnet. Mailkit is connecting to a internal smtp client for the company on port 587 using StartTls

Comment: What version of OpenSSL is your internal smtp client using? The version of SSL used in .NET is not compatible with your internal smtp client.

Comment: The SMTP client requires TLS connection, I am using Openssl version 1.1.1

Comment: There are two sides, the client and the server. What are the versions for both the client and the server. If you do not control the server, use **openssl s_client** to figure out the protocol version that the server is reporting.

Comment: The SMTP client is using protocol TLS 1.2, my Ubuntu server is using TLS 1.3

Comment: The error message is **version too low**. Without more details, who knows what your real problem is.

Comment: Can you explain please what do you mean?

Comment: It means that you need to make sure that your `SmtpClient.SslProtocols` includes `SslProtocols.Tls13`

Comment: Clearly on your local machine, you are using .NET 5.0 with support for TLS v1.3 and your SMTP **server** seems to require TLS v1.3. *BUT* when you run your code on your Ubuntu machine, it seemingly does not support TLS v1.3, so uses TLS v1.2 instead and fails to connect to the SMTP server because of that.